# sending a chunk of data using zigbee

Tags: zigbee

I have some nodes with installed Xbee s2 on them. the zigbee modules configured as routers and coordinator, in zigbee mesh topology. I want to send data from each node to some other nodes.

question:
how I have to send data? here is a pseudo code that I have in mind. I want to know if there is any API in zigbee stack that I can use for this, and if I miss anything:

```
init_network;
fragment_data_to_frames;
fork();
if(process_is_parent)
     for(i=0;iMbum_frames;i++){
        send_frame(i);
        wait(x miliseconds)// how much do I have to wait? or do I have to wait upon receiving ack,i.e. wait(ack(i));
     }
}

if(process_is_child){
        check_acknowledgment_packets();//does zigbee notify me that the frame is lost? or I have handle it by myself, e.g. by assuming frame is lost after specific time.
}
resend_lost_frames;
```

in the destination node, how I can retrieve the data? Do I have to handle it by myself by checking the sequence number and profile, and concatenating the packets? or Zigbee stack will do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

XBee radio modules in API mode will generate a "Transmit Status" frame to indicate that a frame number was received by the remote module.  There's no guarantee that the host on the other side successfully processed it, since it's a network-layer acknowledgement and not application-layer.

How much data are you planning to send?  ZigBee was designed for low-speed, low-volume data transmission.  If you're just using XBee modules, you can make use of their proprietary protocols (like transparent serial).  For interoperability, you'll need to read up on the ZigBee Cluster Library and how it uses general commands and attributes to transfer information between nodes.

Comment: the size of data is about hundreds of floating point numbers.

Comment: can Zigbee application layer handle segmenting the data, sending them, checking for acks, and re-sending the lost frames, and in the receiver node concatenating frames together to retrieve the original data, and ? we already reading the transmit status, but I want to know it there is any API and zigbee cluster library that do it for us automatically.